# Can't update user email with updateEmail(currentUser, newEmail) from Firebase auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple web app using React-TS and Firebase. A user can signup with email and password, a user should also be able to update their profile. I want a user to be able to update their email and I'm trying to use the updateEmail() function from Firebase/auth but it gives me an error when trying to change the email.

"Firebase: Please verify the new email before changing email. (auth/operation-not-allowed)."

```
// Update email IF it has changed
      if (data.email !== (currentUser.email ?? "")) {
        await setEmail(data.email);
      }
```

setEmail() looks like this:

```
const setEmail = (email: string) => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      throw new Error('Current User is Null!')
    }
      return updateEmail(currentUser, email)
    }
```

On a previous project, this error never occurred. If an error occurred it was only because the user needed to have logged in recently, so the solution was to log out then log in again and then you were free to change email, no problems. But now I get this error?

Comment: Have you seen this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?authuser=0#re-authenticate_a_user

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you ever able to figure it out? I've spent hours searching.

Comment: @DeepThought42 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77175592/unexpected-auth-operation-not-allowed-error-when-linking-anonymous-account-wit